# How to upload files from Brackets to Github?

Tags: github, file-upload

Sorry, Im a complete newbie. Ive just created a simple web page (html and css files) with Brackets text editor, but Im having trouble uploading it to Github. In Github, I have created a new repository, and now I should add the files. But I basically don't understand how this works on Brackets. I can't drag the files from Brackets (Github doesnt react to them in any way), I can't download or copy the files from Brackets. So how I'm I supposed to upload them? Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the project name should reveal the path it's stored in

[image: Hovering over the project name should reveal the path it's stored in.]
Open the file in your file browser of choice, then upload the files to your GitHub repository.